# why does the do while skip scanf when none digit character is inputted

Tags: c, scanf, do-loops

In c I have this snippet

```
    int n=0; 
    do {
        printf("random text\n");
        scanf("%d", &n); 
    } while ( n < 1 || n > 10);
```

when the user inputs anything other than a number the loop spams the `printf` without waiting for user input

why does this happen and how do I fix this

Comment: Always a bug: not testing the return value from scanf.

Comment: You fix it by not using `scanf`, Use `fgets` and then apply `sscanf` or other string processing functions.

Comment: @WeatherVane what if you can't use anything except for `scanf`

Comment: Who or what forces you to use `scanf`? It's a very limited function that causes more harm than good. It seems to be a teacher's favourite. Most teachers are not actually programmers though.

Comment: @Cheatah yes it is a requirement to use this function I know other functions but i am not allowed to use them

Comment: Well now you know why the function sucks. You could test for the return value. If it's not 1, have some more forgiving `scanf` format string eat up the input and try again.

Comment: Your instructor should not have restricted you to `scanf`, and you may tell them we said so. Perhaps refer them to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf

Comment: If the teacher is making you use `scanf` then you could spend an hour or two with a little test program and the man pages, particularly with a loop where more than one entry is needed. Note that understanding how different format specifiers handle whitespace in the input, and in the format string itself, is critical to using the function successfully, and without messy kludges. There are many pitfalls with that function family, it really is tricky and worth spending some time on.

Comment: The problem mentioned in the question as well as the solution is mentioned in section 1 of the following guide: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to skip the current content of the buffer if it does not contain a valid number. For example

```
int n=0; 
do {
    printf("random text\n");
    if ( scanf("%d", &n) == 0 )
    {
        scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
    }    
} while ( n < 1 || n > 10);
```

Pay attention to that this prompt

```
    printf("random text\n");
```

is confusing when you expect from the user to enter a number.

In general you should also add a check for EOF. For example

```
int result = 1;
int n=0; 
do {
    n = 0;
    printf("random text\n");

    result = scanf("%d", &n);

    if ( result == 0 )
    {
        scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
    }
    else if ( result == EOF )
    {
        break;
    }  
} while ( n < 1 || n > 10);

if ( result == EOF ) exit( 1 );
//...
```

Comment: @Oka how can you do this with user input?

Comment: @packet_sniffer See my appended answer.

Comment: Testing `result == EOF` (with scope change)  rather than `n == 0` has an advantage as the value of `n` on `EOF` return due to _input error_ is indeterminant.

Comment: I am think of the exceptional case if `scanf("%d", &n)` reads `'1'`, `'2'`, _input error_ and then returns `EOF`.  From my reading of the spec, the value of `n` is not certainly remain 0.  I shall review this odd case.

Answer (score 3):

When the user enters bad data, the un-converted data remains in the input buffer.

You then repeatedly attempt to convert that data to an integer, and fail each time, leading to infinite repetition.

You can clear the input buffer up to the next new-line in case of failure.

Personally, I *generally* prefer to read in a line to start with, then attempt to convert that with `sscanf`, on this general order:

```cpp
char buffer[256];
do {
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
} while (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &n) == 0 || n < 1 || n > 10);
```

Generally it's better to wrap the calls to `fgets` and `sscanf` up in a function though, so you can return some error indication when either one fails (since this doesn't check the return value from `fgets` it can/will continue trying to read, even if reading from the stream fails).

Comment: how do I fix this

Comment: Maybe `sscanf(buffer, "%d", &n) != 1`?  I am often concerned about `scanf()` returning `EOF, 0, 1,...`  Since only `1` is the desired input, perhaps test against that.  Pedantically, since overflow is UB with `"%d"`, maybe `"%4d"` or some input limitation?  Still, answer in on the right track.